# If $f(x,y,z) = 0 $, why can we say that x(y,z), y(x,z) and z(x,y)?

Tags: functions

In my thermodynamics lecture course we were talking about equations of state and such, our lecturer then said that if $f$ is a function of state, with state variables $x,y,z$, then we can rewrite any of the state variables in terms of the other state variables. Putting that into maths, it means:
$f(x,y,z)$ = 0 , then $x(y,z), y(x,z)$ and $z(x,y)$. I just wanted to know if theres a theorem or a general proof for this as I can think of a few cases where it would be difficult to re arrange to get one variable in terms of another.

For example, $x^2cosy+y^3sinx=0$, I dont think you can explicitly express y in terms of x here. Does anyone know what my lecturer was trying to get at?

Comment: There's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: The “Implicit function theorem” states that (under some conditions) one variable can be (locally) expressed as a function of the other variables. That does not mean that this function is *explicitly* given.